# how to pass parameters in http get request?

Tags: flutter, curl, dart

i would like to pass parameters in a http get request in my flutter app. here is the code cUrl code i want  to transform in a http get request.

[image]

and here is the code i want to ameliorate

```
Future<http.Response> getTarget(String type, String q) async {
  try {
    final response = await dio.Dio().get(
      'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/search',
      queryParameters: {'type': type, 'q': q, 'access_token': ACCESS_TOKEN},
    );
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error: $e');
    print(e.code);
  }
}
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: Use this website to convert your curl to Dart. https://curl.trillworks.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout the following [link](https://pub.dev/documentation/dio/latest/#examples) (see examples section).

As per your question, you can send the parameters in `queryParameters` (as you already did) or you can pass them in the URL as in the following:

```
Future<http.Response> getTarget(String type, String q) async {
  try {
    final response = await dio.Dio().get(
      "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/search?type=${type}&q=${q}&access_token=${ACCESS_TOKEN}"
    );
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error: $e');
    print(e.code);
  }
}
```